# Does there exist a fibre bundle $K(\mathbb{Z}_4,1)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$ with fiber $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibre-bundles

Does there exist a fibration $K(\mathbb{Z}_4,1)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$, evidently with fiber $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$?

Comment: In homotopy theory, any map is a fibration. The one you are looking for is merely the one induced by the exact sequence of groups $1\to\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_4\to\Bbb Z_2\to0$.

Answer (score 2):

Every map can be replaced by a weakly equivalent fibration, using the path space (see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36430/every-map-can-be-replaced-by-a-weakly-equivalent-fibration)). Can you see how to use this to answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Tom. I was thinking about constructing explicit locally trivial bundle, I did not mention it in the question though.

Comment: If you want a locally trivial fibre bundle, then you should say so in your question. A fibration (in the sense of Serre or Hurewicz) is a considerably weaker notion. In particular, path spaces are fibrations but (I think) not necessarily fibre bundles.